# How to get a specific number of items from a json array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json document with the US states, in this form:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Alabama",
        "abbreviation" : "AL"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Alaska",
        "abbreviation" : "AK"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Arizona",
        "abbreviation" : "AZ"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Arkansas",
        "abbreviation" : "AR"
    },
    {
        "name" : "California",
        "abbreviation" : "CA"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Colorado",
        "abbreviation" : "CO"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Connecticut",
        "abbreviation" : "CT"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Delaware",
        "abbreviation" : "DE"
    }
]
```

What I did is to decode the json document, then split the smaller arrays in their respective elements, by name and abbreviation. It echos the whole list of arrays properly.

```
$arrays = json_decode(file_get_contents('states.json'));
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $state_name = $array->{'name'};
    $state_abbreviation = $array->{'abbreviation'};
    echo '<p>' . $state_name . ' abbreviates ' . $state_abbreviation . '</p>';
}
```

But I need to be able to generate a specific number of random arrays from the big array which is the json file. Tried array_rand and there was no result. If the list has more than 50 items, from what I've read, mt_rand would be appropiate, because it might be faster and randomizes better. Only I didn't find too much info on mt_rand, except for numeric arrays.

How do I generate only 4, for example?

Thanks in advance!

And this is the solution with a small twist (slice factor), provided by [@EinLinuus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14427036/einlinuus). Thanks, EinLinuus & [Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1685196/michel).

```
$arrays = json_decode(file_get_contents('states.json'));
shuffle($arrays);
$slice_factor = 4;
$arrays = array_slice($arrays, 0, $slice_factor);
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $state_name = $array->{'name'};
    $state_abbreviation = $array->{'abbreviation'};
    echo '<p>' . $state_name . ' abbreviates ' . $state_abbreviation . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Shuffle the array randomly with [`shuffle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and then pick the first four with [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your array stored in the variable `$array`, first shuffle the array with `shuffle($array)`.
Now you have a random array and you can get the first `x` elements with `array_slice($array, 0, x)`;

Example:

```
$array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; // Your array
shuffle($array); // Shuffle the array, it could be now [4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3]
$result = array_slice($array, 0, 3); // Get first 3 elements, in this case [4, 1, 6];
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I will post the solution in the question above.

Comment: Is it possible to shuffle with mt_rand?

Comment: What do you mean? The function `shuffle()` is made to shuffle an array, why not use it?

Comment: because it will get the same elements of the array every time you shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **array_rand** function to get randomly selected elements from the array.No shuffling or slicing.

```
$arr = range( 1, 20 );
$pick_random_items = 4;
$randoms = array_rand( $arr, $pick_random_items );
```